# Work or not : python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I use this code to recognize QR and EAN codes. It works fine.

But after few hours it stops with error. Even when i do not use it. Why it happens?
The error is below. It says that samothing is wrong with sky = frame[800:1200,330:1500].
I am new with Python so i do not have a clue.

error:

**sky = frame[800:1200,330:1500]**

**python TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

````
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from gpiozero import Buzzer
from time import sleep

qr= "1"
ean="1"

def wyslijEmail(tresc):
    port = 465  # For SSL
    smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
    sender_email = "***"  # Enter your address
    receiver_email = "***"  # Enter receiver address
    password = "***"
    
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, tresc)


def decoder(image):
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(image,0)
    barcode = decode(gray_img)
    global a
    global qr
    global ean
    buzzer = Buzzer(14)
    kodQR = "QR"
    ean13 = "EAN"
    

    for obj in barcode:
        points = obj.polygon
        (x,y,w,h) = obj.rect
        pts = np.array(points, np.int32)
        pts = pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
        cv2.polylines(image, [pts], True, (0, 255, 0), 3)

        barcodeData = obj.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = obj.type
        
        if kodQR in barcodeType:
            print("qr")
            if qr != str(barcodeData):
                qr=str(barcodeData)
                wyslijEmail(barcodeData)
                print("wysylam @")
                buzzer.on()
                sleep(1)
                buzzer.off()
                sleep(1)
            else :
                print("nowy kod")
        elif ean13 in barcodeType:
            print("ean")
            if ean != str(barcodeData):
                ean=str(barcodeData)
                wyslijEmail(barcodeData)
                print("wysylam @")
                buzzer.on()
                sleep(1)
                buzzer.off()
                sleep(1)
            else :
                print("nowy kod")
            
        string = "Data " + str(barcodeData) + " | Type " + str(barcodeType)
        
        cv2.putText(frame, string, (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.8,(255,0,0), 2)
        print("Barcode: "+barcodeData +" | Type: "+barcodeType )
        print(a)
        a=a+1

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 2592)
cap.set(4, 1944)
a=0


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    sky = frame[800:1200,330:1500]
    decoder(sky)
    cv2.imshow('Image', sky)
    code = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if code == ord('q'):
        break```
````

Comment: `cap.read` returns a boolean (`ret`) whether the frame was read correctly, have you checked the value of that? it appears if that is false, that you cannot use the `frame` value, since it is not read correctly, but you simply discard that?

Comment: I do not check it. But this code work fine. It reads, sends email. When i leave it working , after few hours it stops with this error. Do you think that suddenly **cap** is empty?

Comment: Well that is the thing about fault states, they tend to only appear when there is a fault. So that your code works for hours at a time, does not mean that it is guaranteed to work in all cases. When the API exposes a state which informs of the validity of the data you are given, it would be my advice to check it, and react to it. The actual problem that you see is because `frame` is `None`, which might occur if `cap` is empty I guess, but there might be other reasons which it is impractical to determine given the limited information in the post. Best suggestion is to check the status you get

Comment: OK. I will check if **cap/frame** is not empty. I will leave it for some time to chceck it. Thank you for now.

Comment: Today morning it seems to be crashed totaly. The only thing i could do on raspberry pi with monitor it was a photo (sorry for that!): https://www.dropbox.com/s/02m272lby6681va/20221025_095852.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `frame` is not available yet, you can make sure it is by assessing

```py
if frame is None:
    continue
```